# Создание токена на сети Solana. Проблема с названием

Tags: linux, криптография, token

Создаю свой токен на сети Solana. В целом уже всё готово, кроме названия, сокращения и логотипа. Пытаюсь добавить через консоль, но выдает ошибку:

```
$ spl-token initialize-metadata EsguxzqPaUmjpoVaK...KLCov7UUSZ NAME NAME https://arweave.net/JHc1m-AyPhKBDLfOTu18XMGVXeaxZOoFfU9bLlQrqrk
Error: Client(Error { request: Some(SendTransaction), kind: RpcError(RpcResponseError { code: -32002, message: "Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 1: custom program error: 0xc", data: SendTransactionPreflightFailure(RpcSimulateTransactionResult { err: Some(InstructionError(1, Custom(12))), logs: Some(["Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]", "Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success", "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [1]", "Program log: Error: Invalid instruction", "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 863 of 399850 compute units", "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA failed: custom program error: 0xc"]), accounts: None, units_consumed: Some(150), return_data: None }) }) })
```

Облазил гитхаб проекта, там указаны две ссылки для создания токена. Одна не работает у меня, другая(token creator) выдает ошибку при создании.

Как мне изменить хотя бы название токена, не говоря о логотипе?